# Given a linear operator $T$, find $I + T + T^2+\dots+T^{2004}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The following question is of very little importance but yet not entirely clear, hence:

Let there be a Linear operator T going from $R^3[x]$ to $R^3[x]$ defined by : 
$$
T(ax^2 + bx +c) = (a+c)x^2 + bx +c. 
$$

Find: 
$$
 (I + T + T^2.....T^{2004})(a,b,c).
$$

Attempt at a Solution: From a few tests we can see that: $T^n = (a+nc)\,x^2 + bx + c$.

Also, the requested matrix can be represented as: 
$$
I(ax^2 + bx +c) + T(ax^2 + bx +c) + T^2(ax^2 + bx +c) +.....T^{2004}(ax^2 + bx +c),
$$
 which will eventually equal $((2005a+2009010c)x^2 +2005bx + 2005c)$.

The official answer is however: $((2005a+2009011c)x^2 +2005b + 2005c)$.

Any advice?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Bak1139: Please make sure the edits are correct. Helps to format using MathJax and this can still use some cleanup. Regards

Comment: wow this is messed up...

Comment: the transformation is from the polynomial subspace R3[x] to R3[x]

Comment: I think this has to be tackled from the Linear Algebra view of this problem rather than the arithmetical one...there must be a reason why they put it this way...a similar problem was solved with just the same result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the official answer there is a typo: it should be $2005bx$ and not just $2005b$. Here, you are absolutely right.

For the $2009010$ instead of $2009011$, here it is: you have to sum $1+2+3+\dots+2004$. This equals $2004\cdot 2005 /2 = 2009010$.

So, you are right again. And the book is wrong.

Comment: I think this has to be tackled from the Linear Algebra view of this problem rather than the arithmetical one...there must be a reason why they put it this way...a similar problem was solved with just the same result.

Comment: From the point of view of linear algebra, the matrix is upper triangular, which is a fancy way to say that the calculation of its powers are exactly what you did...